# Mysql Count query returning "Query was empty"

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am using the following script to try and count the rows in a table, the problem I keep getting is the error :

Query was empty
Quiz Name

and a blank page. Im new to COUNT, so I think I might be making a mess of it :-S . 
My database layout is as follows :

```
itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions cf_id ,cf_uid,cf_created ,cf_modified, cf_ipaddress,    cf_user_id, quizID, questionID, quizquestion, quizanswer1, quizanswer2, quizanswer3, quizanswer4,     questionformat ,correctanswer
```

The script I am working on is :

```
    // Define Quiz Variables
    $quiz = $row['quizID'];
    $quizcfid = $row['cf_id'];
    $quizname = $row['quizname'];
    // Finish Define Quiz Variables  

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Make a MySQL Connection

    $query8 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'numberofquestions' FROM employees WHERE quizID='$quiz'"; 

    $result8 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Print out result
    while($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($result8)){
        echo 'There are '. $row8['COUNT(quizID)'] . ' questions';
    } 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running the wrong query, you are running `$query` and not `$query8`

change to this :

```
$result8 = mysql_query($query8) or die(mysql_error());
```

in a second glance, you should also change to :

```
echo 'There are '. $row8['numberofquestions'] . ' questions';
```

as you set `numberofquestion` to be the count alias.

Comment: Thanks, that has gotten rid of the error, but I now get There are questions echo'd out, it doesn't appear to be echoing the number of questions.

Comment: Thanks that's sorted now, I thought I had copied and pasted that correctly but apparently not........Its been a long day ! :-)

Comment: You welcome. i've browsed through your questions and you should start accpeting answers on your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result8 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$result8 = mysql_query($query8) or die(mysql_error());
```

since i'm guessing the variable $query is empty which you were passing it before.

As for COUNT() stay away from COUNT(*), instead use COUNT(field_name) and for even faster results ensure that the field_name is in the index being used.

Count simply counts the total rows returned for the specified field.

Also, be carefull of using COUNT(*) in innodb as it will force a TABLE SCAN if not used with a WHERE clause on an index.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your following line:

```
echo 'There are '. $row8['COUNT(quizID)'] . ' questions';
```

for this one:

```
echo 'There are '. $row8['numberofquestions'] . ' questions';
```

As `numberofquestions` is the name of the only field from your query result set.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of rows in your result use mysql_num_rows:

```
$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misstyped this

```
$result8 = mysql_query($query8) or die(mysql_error());
```

and also

```
echo 'There are '. $row8['numberofquestions'] . ' questions';
```

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sql i see rigth.
But i use this

```
$result8 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result8);


echo 'There are '.$count[0].' '. questions';
```

**Other Option:**

```
 while($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($result8,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo 'There are '. $row8['numberofquestions'] . ' questions';
    }
```